# Most performative way of performing the grouping information of an PHP array

Tags: php, laravel, logic

I have an array generate by **Database Query Builder** of Laravel 5.1.x.

```
array:96 [▼
  0 => {#1256 ▼
    +"customer_id": 58
    +"city": "Rio de Janeiro"
    +"program_id": 3
    +"program": "PROGRAMA XPTO"
    +"subregion": "SUB-REGIÃO UM"
    +"mr_name": "2015/02"
    +"info_1": 8
    +"info_2": 9
    +"info_3": 239
    +"info_4": 10
    +"info_5": 295
    +"info_6": "12.3430962343096"
  }
  1 => {#1255 ▼
    +"customer_id": 58
    +"city": "Rio de Janeiro"
    +"program_id": 3
    +"program": "PROGRAMA XPTO"
    +"subregion": "SUB-REGIÃO UM"
    +"mr_name": "2015/03"
    +"info_1": 8
    +"info_2": 9
    +"info_3": 239
    +"info_4": 21
    +"info_5": 377
    +"info_6": "7.51145646543136"
  }
  2 => {#1254 ▼
    +"customer_id": 58
    +"city": "Rio de Janeiro"
    +"program_id": 3
    +"program": "PROGRAMA XPTO"
    +"subregion": "SUB-REGIÃO UM"
    +"mr_name": "2015/04"
    +"info_1": 8
    +"info_2": 9
    +"info_3": 239
    +"info_4": 19
    +"info_5": 607
    +"info_6": "13.3670997577626"
  }
  ...
]
```

Problem: I want to group that information like this.

```
array: [▼
    "customers" => { ▼
        +"Rio de Janeiro": array [▼
            +"programs": array [▼
                "PROGRAMA XPTO": array [▼
                    +"subregions": array [▼
                        "SUB-REGIÃO UM": array [▼
                            "months": array [▼
                                "2015/02": array [],
                                "2015/03": array [],
                                "2015/04": array [],
                                "2015/05": array [],
                                "2015/06": array [],
                                "2015/07": array [],
                                ...
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
  ...
]
```

Using pure PHP and iterate each value I get an extra 5-10 seconds for render the page (code below):

```
if (!empty($result)) {
    $city = $result[0]->city;
    $program = null;
    $subregion = null;
    $school = null;
    $class = null;

    $data['customers'] = [];

    foreach ($result as $r => $row) {
        if (isset($data[$row->city])) {
            continue;
        }

        $city = $row->city;
        $data['customers'][$city] = [];
        $data['customers'][$city]['customer_id'] = $row->customer_id;

        foreach ($result as $pid => $programs) {
            if ($city == $programs->city) {
                if (isset($data[$city]['programs'][$programs->program])) {
                    continue;
                }

                $program = $programs->program;

                $data['customers'][$city]['programs'][$program] = [
                    'program_id' => $programs->program_id,
                    'total_escolas' => false,
                    'total_turmas' => false,
                    'students' => false,
                    'subregions' => []
                ];

                foreach ($result as $subId => $subregions) {
                    if (($city == $subregions->city)
                        and ($program == $subregions->program)
                    ) {
                        $subregion = $subregions->subregion;
                        $data['customers'][$city]['programs'][$program]['subregions'][$subregions->subregion] = [
                            'months' => []
                        ];

                        foreach ($result as $mId => $months) {
                            if (($city == $months->city)
                                and ($program == $months->program)
                                and ($subregion == $months->subregion)
                                and !empty($data['customers'][$city]['programs'][$program]['subregions'][$subregion]['months'][$months->mr_name])
                            ) {
                                $mr_name = $months->mr_name;
                                $data['customers'][$city]['programs'][$program]['subregions'][$subregion]['months'][$mr_name] = [
                                    'info_1' => $months->info_1,
                                    'info_2' => $months->info_2,
                                    'info_3' => $months->info_3,
                                    'info_4' => $months->info_4,
                                    'info_5' => $months->info_5,
                                    'info_6' => $months->info_6
                                ];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obs.: my query run in 137ms and the page load in avg 8 seconds.

---

- What am I doing wrong?
- There is another way to group these data?

---

If you need more information tell me.

Comment: Nested loops. Your algorithm runs at O(n^4). Yikes. Consider restructuring the data or displaying it accordion style and loading the data when things are expanded with an ajax request.

Comment: Yes I know that. But I not find the best solution yet ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, you have 2 options. The key is to order your values so you can do a single pass over them. In your case, the order should be:

1. city
2. program
3. subregion
4. mr_name

#### option 1, in database

Add 4 [`orderBy()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) clauses to your query to achieve that order.

#### option 2, in php

Use PHP's [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function to sort your values in the required order.

#### Finally

Use the sorted array in 1 pass. While iterating over the sorted values, use variables to remember the city, program, subregion and mr_name of the previous entry. When the current subregion differs from the last one, you know you're starting a new subregion and the last one has no more elements.

Comment: Goode idea! I will try that. Thanks my friend.

Comment: I was doing pretty much what you said in the above code, but my comparison was incorrect because I forgot to add the index `['customers']` in array in some locations. So... I fix that and works. Thanks for the idea anyway!